# How to get a current date for upload_to in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

Since some image files have name conflicts, I decided to make the system to change a uploaded file's name automatically. However, after changing the system, I got in trouble with getting a current date for the file path.

This is how my previous `Image` model looks like, and it stores an image with a name like `boutique/index/2018/9/20/FILE_NAME.jpg`.

```
class Image(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    image = ImageField(..., upload_to='boutique/index/index/%Y/%m/%d')
    ...
```

After that, I changed it to like this. This successfully changes a uploaded image's name automatically. However, it stores a name like `boutique/%Y/%m/%d/FILE_NAME.jpg`.

```
def image_path(instance, filename):
    basefilename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
    randomstr = ''.join((random.choice(chars)) for x in range(10))
    return 'boutique/index/%Y/%m/%d/{imageid}/{basename}{randomstring}{ext}'.format(imageid=instance.store.domainKey, basename=basefilename, randomstring=randomstr, ext=file_extension)

class Image(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    image = ImageField(..., upload_to=image_path)
    ...
```

Like you see the above, the problem is that `%Y`, `%m`, and `%d` don't provide date data I need anymore. What is wrong here? `image_path` function returns the same thing in the same place. I don't know why they are just like recognized as a normal string

Comment: You can use epoch time or combination of epoch time and user id to avoid name conflicts. Or is there any specific reason to use this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set those values manually.

Add the import

```
from datetime import datetime
```

And replace in your function %Y, %m, %d with {year}, {month}, {day} variables and add the values to the format call.

```
def image_path(instance, filename):
    basefilename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
    randomstr = ''.join((random.choice(chars)) for x in range(10))
    _now = datetime.now()

    return 'boutique/index/{year}/{month}/{day}/{imageid}/{basename}{randomstring}{ext}'.format(
        imageid=instance.store.domainKey, 
        basename=basefilename, randomstring=randomstr, ext=file_extension,
        year=_now.strftime('%Y'), month=_now.strftime('%m'), day=_now.strftime('%d')
        )
```

More about file uploads in [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)